# Power series with products of prime numbers as coefficients

Tags: prime-numbers, power-series

I encountered in my work an infinite series (only even power) with $n^{th}$ coefficient being of the following form:
$$\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot...\cdot(n^{th}  prime)}.$$
I wonder if such series
$$1+\frac{1}{3}\cdot t^2+\frac{1}{3\cdot5}\cdot t^4+\frac{1}{3\cdot5\cdot7}\cdot t^6+...$$

is of wider interest and there exists results regarding its properties. It looks like it might be something of interest to the number theorists. Does this series have some "analytic" expression (e.g. like $e^t$ can be expressen in infinite taylor series)?

Comment: I think you will not find a nice expression for this, simply because you're looking at the primes. You might want to look at https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C30&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @Chinny84 Sorry, just a typo. All powers ar different and even.